# PHP-Resque won't run perform()

Tags: php, php-resque

I am using [PHP-Resque](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque) and can't get the **perform()** method to work. Can anyone tell what I'm missing?

This is my setup:

- I have 3 terminals open running the following:
- `$ php workers.php`
- `$ redis-cli monitor`
- `$ php create.php` (To create a job)
- **workers.php**

  ```
  <?php

  putenv("VVERBOSE=1");
  putenv("LOGGING=1");
  putenv("QUEUE=* php bin/resque"); 
  require_once APPPATH . '../vendor/chrisboulton/php-resque/bin/resque';
  ```
- **create.php**

  ```
  <?php

  $jobId = Resque::enqueue('JESSE', 'Dog', ['hey'], true);
  echo "JobId: $jobId\n";

  $status = new Resque_Job_Status($jobId);
  if ($status->isTracking()) {
      echo "\nStatus: " . $status->get();
  }
  ```

**I always get a JobId and Status of 1. eg:**

```
JobId: 757335754aec172166e8679cc3bfef58
Status: 1
```

**I always get a Redis log that its been inserted. eg:**

```
[2 127.0.0.1:38912] "sadd" "resque:queues" "JESSE"
[2 127.0.0.1:38912] "rpush" "resque:queue:JESSE" "{\"class\":\"Dog\",\"args\":[[\"hey\"]],\"id\":\"757335754aec172166e8679cc3bfef58\"}"
[2 127.0.0.1:38912] "set" "resque:job:757335754aec172166e8679cc3bfef58:status" "{\"status\":1,\"updated\":1398269884,\"started\":1398269884}"
[2 127.0.0.1:38912] "exists" "resque:job:757335754aec172166e8679cc3bfef58:status"
```

**Yet it doesn't seem to be running the perform() method at all:**

```
class Dog {
    public function perform()
    {
        echo 'TEST TEST TEST TEST';

        fwrite('/tmp/resque-output.txt', 'This is running', w);
        fwrite(STDOUT, 'Start job! -> ');
        sleep(1);
        fwrite(STDOUT, 'Job ended!' . PHP_EOL);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have problems setting up php-resque for codeigniter app. This seems a approach for codeigniter . In case YES. How does php workers.php fits in in the context of codeigniter.

Comment: its says "Set QUEUE env var containing the list of queues to work" when I try to run workers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure it's this:

```
putenv("QUEUE=* php bin/resque");
```

That should just be:

```
putenv("QUEUE=*");
```

The second part is the command to start resque, which you're doing differently. As it stands, it's looking for a queue `* php bin/resque` instead of all queues (`*`).

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly, I was Baffled. I got confused reading 3 different tutorials I and there are a few branches that might be dated or newer.

Comment: Yeah I've had some problems with php-resque, as the repo is significantly newer than their last stable release.